Redirect if not serving a PHP file
Consider these files on-disk:
/dir/index.php
/dir/page.php
/dir/index.html
/dir/image.jpg

Consider these desired outcomes:
https://www.example.com/dir             Serve index.php
https://www.example.com/dir/            Serve index.php
https://www.example.com/dir/index.php   Serve index.php
  ^ in the absence of an index.php file, a redirect should happen in these scenarios
https://www.example.com/dir/page.php    Serve page.php
https://www.example.com/dir/index.html  Redirect to Google
https://www.example.com/dir/image.jpg   Redirect to Google

Consider this config:
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir(/|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.google.com [R=302,L,NC,QSA]

Actual outcomes:
https://www.example.com/dir             Redirect to Google (bad)
https://www.example.com/dir/            Redirect to Google (bad)
https://www.example.com/dir/index.php   Serve index.php
https://www.example.com/dir/page.php    Serve page.php
https://www.example.com/dir/index.html  Redirect to Google
https://www.example.com/dir/image.jpg   Redirect to Google

